# How to append 2 html elements in a row with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append

I would like to append some html content to a list to end up like this,

```
<ul>
<li>
<input />
<label><img></label>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'm using the append method for the readability but the "input" nested the others html element (which is normal i think), how can I achieve the upper form of display with the append method ?

```
  function updateFunction(id, image, label) {
    $.colorbox.close();

    $("#checkbox_list").append(
    $("<li/>", {
      "id": "medias_bloc_"+id,
      html: $("<input/>", {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "value": id,
        "class": "check_box",
        "checked": "checked"
      })
    })
  );

    $("#medias_bloc"+id).append(
    $("<label/>", {
      "for": "medias_list_"+id,
      "html": $("<img/>", {
        "src": "/uploads/Media/thumb/"+image,
        "width": 100,
        "height":100
      })
    })
  );

  }
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("<li/>", {
  "id": "medias_bloc_"+id,
  html: $("<input/>", {
    "type": "checkbox",
    "value": id,
    "class": "check_box",
    "checked": "checked"
  })
}).append(
$("<label/>", {
  "for": "medias_list_"+id,
  "html": $("<img/>", {
    "src": "/uploads/Media/thumb/"+image,
    "width": 100,
    "height":100
})
```

The `<label>` element will append directly to the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just change this line:

```
    $("#medias_bloc"+id).append(
```

to this:

```
    $("#checkbox_list").append(
```

Edit: No, wait, misread your code; this won't work.

Comment: This would cause the label and image to be put inside of `ul` instead of inside of the `li`.